# java class.getResource returns null in vscode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, ide, getresource

Trying to run a file as a part of an assignment. File was given with the following lines

```
System.getProperty("user.dir");
    URL edgesPath = CSI2510.class.getResource(edgesFilename);
    BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(edgesPath.getFile()));
```

However getResource returns null. The file it is trying to find is in the same directory. I've tried adding "\", "/", and "./" with no luck. I'm confident the file name is correct and even copying the path to the file doesn't work.

Is there a setting I need to use? The course never actually taught us how to use Java IDEs and I've felt like I've been using it wrong. How could I add a folder full of java and text files into a project? How do I set the whole thing up?

Comment: What does the first line of code have to do with anything? --- *"... is in the same directory"* Same as what? The `.java` file? The `.class` file? The project? --- *Hint: It needs to be in the same directory as the `.class` file. Verify that it is, and remember that the `.class` file is not necessarily in the same folder as the `.java` file.*

Answer (score 0):

`SomeClass.class.getResource` doesn't find files, it finds resources, and it looks in the same place that the JVM looks for class files. But it's not quite a file system; `..` does not work, and dots are treated special in any case (all dots except the last are converted to a slash).

For example, this: class Test { void foo() { Test.class.getResource("Test.java"); } }

would find itself. With *OUT* a leading slash, you start in the same directory  your class is in (even inside a jar if need be), and you can visit subdirs from there but not parents. You can also start your string with a leading slash in which case it'll look in the root of the classpath entry.

A simple trick is to do this:

```
System.out.println(CSI2510.class.getResource("CSI2510.class"));
```

this will tell you where you're looking.

Comment: Thanks that was super useful, do you know how I can get it to give the right place. It seems that vsCode is sending me to `file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/workspaceStorage/7e2229f9c4144c98bae89a2f331db119/redhat.java/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin/csi2510_project/CSI2510.class`

Comment: Check that 'bin' dir for the file you want. if it is not anywhere inside it (on windows: `dir /s`, on anything else, `find .` in that `bin` dir), then that is vscode failing to be a good IDE. file a bug, or figure out how to make it copy such resources / put the root dir in your src tree also on the classpath on a boot. For the what it's worth, eclipse properly copies all non-java files to the bin dir automatically, for example.